# Adding text in more than one language (at the same time)

Tags: admin, wp-admin, multi-language, language

I am building a wordpress site. On the upper-right hand corner of every page on the site
I am going to have two (or more) flags, and clicking on any given flag should cause the
site to display the text in the language corresponding to the given flag. In order to
do this, I should be able to enter the text for WordPress pages, posts, blogrolls,
etc... in all supported languages at once.

How does WordPress achieve this? (I also want to make one language the default so
that if one text is missing in one language then it is displayed in the default
language, but I would like the admin interface to be flexible enough so that
any given text must be entered in both (or all supported) languages at once,
with a single submit.

Do I need a plugin to achieve this behavior? How can I achieve such a setup?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress doesn't have built-in features for a site that is served in multiple languages. Yes WordPress has features for translating the UI labels into different languages, but not for the actual content. You are going to need to use a plugin that basically keeps multiple versions of each Post for each language and has means for the user to select the language. The [WordPress Codex has an article that overviews the different ways to achieve a multilingual setups](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress).

**Articles to help you pick a plugin**

- [The Complete Guide To A Multilingual WordPress Site](http://www.cpothemes.com/guides/multilingual-wordpress-site-guide)
- [How to Create a Multilingual WordPress Site](https://managewp.com/create-multilingual-wordpress-site)
- [Top 6 Translation Plugins for Your WordPress Site](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/top-6-translation-plugins-for-your-wordpress-site/)